# Passing params to and from layout.tsx in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to understand how I can pass properties from a page to a layout and vice versa using Next.js.

My scenarios is below:

- I have a stepper component (standard Material UI stepper: [link](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stepper/)) in my `layout.tsx` that shows what page I'm on.
- each page is a separate route (note: I'm using app router).
- the 'next' button is on each `page.tsx` (not layout.tsx).
- when I press the 'next' button on the page I want my `page.tsx` to tell the stepper component on the `layout.tsx` to highlight the next step.

Currently I don't have a scenario where I need to pass data from the `layout.tsx` to the `page.tsx`, but I'm pretty sure I will very shortly.

Comment: Based on the documentation from NextJS on [this page](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts) it seems that "Passing data between a parent layout and its children is not possible"

Answer (score -1):

It is better to link your Stepper's current step to a Router parameter, so your button will just open a link with the next value of the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I definitely could look at restructuring it, but I'm keen to understand how this is actually done (or if it can be done) also.